# what is the current android equivalent of UITabBar

Tags: android, android-layout, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

There are many old questions here on the matter. And they all mention that the former mechanism is now deprecated. Is there a present means for created Tab based applications in android similar to how it's done in iOS, i.e. using UITabBar/UITabBarController?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: please dont copy iOS UI to and android app

Comment: Since few developers monitoring the `android` tag also develop for iOS, please explain in your own words what "Tab based applications in android similar to how it's done in iOS, i.e. using UITabBar/UITabBarController" means. Feel free to include screenshots.

Comment: @CommonsWare I finally found out how it's called in android: `Bottom bar of Action Bar` according to http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html. I still haven't figured how to implement it yet.

Comment: [Tabs do not go on the bottom in Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html). In particular, there is no way to put tabs in the split (bottom) portion of the split action bar.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am reading a lot on the subject, but I am still confused on how this would work, then. How do I get the Top Bar? I see that there are three: `Main action bar`, `Top bar`, `Bottom bar`. Per your correction, I cannot really just have a `Bottom bar`. How do I make sure I get the first two? My goal is to have a SearchView in the `Main action bar` and then my tabs in the `Top bar`. I am trying using the page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. But I am not making as much progress as I had hoped.

Comment: For instance what is `yourapp` in the line `yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`? I try to put the project name and then the package name and it's not compiling. Do you have any sample code that does the first two action bars (without the bottom one). I see it in the Google Play Store app.

Comment: Because my tab bar is to be present on all views/scenes of my app, I am hoping to use the xml version that can be inflated using `onCreateOptionsMenu` as opposed to the one pointed to by @FrankN.Stein

Comment: The best solution right now to having tabs be at the top of your main content (i.e., below the action bar) is to use a `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`).

Comment: i would mark @CommonsWare comment as an answer, i suggest  to make it an answer by the question asker ( Katedral Pillon ) or CommonsWare

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android studio, you can use it to generate up-to-date code samples for tabs.

---

`file > new > activity > Tabbed activity`

Generates an activity with a tabbar at the top, and uses `Fragments` for the tabs.

---

`file > new > activity > Bottom Navigation Activity`

Tabbar at the bottom. You will have to implement the tabbing yourself, I would recommend using `Fragments` here as well. You can generate fragments using `file > new > Fragment`, and learn how to swap them at runtime: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime